# Who offered to buy Charlie's soul?

Tags: plot-explanation, scent-of-a-woman

Towards the end of *Scent of a Woman*, Al Pacino's character Lt. Col. Slade makes a passionate speech defending the protagonist, Charlie Simms. In it, he says that Charlie's soul is intact and non-negotiable, and he knows this because someone "offered to buy it". Who is he referring to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[From the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scent_of_a_Woman_(1992_film)):

> Once George has left the office, Trask (the headmaster) offers Charlie a bribe: a letter of recommendation that would virtually guarantee his acceptance to Harvard.